# Sum of 1.5-powers of natural numbers using Euler-Maclaurin Formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

Hi, I have read this [Sum of 1.5-powers of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393811/sum-of-1-5-powers-of-natural-numbers) and answers posted by Mark Viola. However, I am not too sure on how he got to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVmLQ.png).
Can anyone show me as I am quite new to series?

Comment: Did you follow the link to the Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Comment: The formula in the linked answer is off at the constant term (see Claude Leibovici's answer for correct expansion). In general, [Euler-Maclaurin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) is great for those parts which diverges at large $n$. For constant term and beyond, [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) or [Mellin's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) will be a better tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple using the generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\frac 32}=H_n^{\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ Using their asymptotics for large values of $n$, you have
$$S_n=\frac25n^{5/2}+\frac12 n^{3/2}+\frac18n^{1/2}+\zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{1920}n^{-3/2}-\frac {1 }{21504}n^{-5/2}+O\left({n^{-7/2}}\right)$$
$$\zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\sim -0.0254852$$