# What is an approximate closed form for sum of $n^n$ series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I read about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula which is **Euler-Maclaurain** and I did my calculation to find the constants. However, the answer differ greatly from expected value. Are there any other series which is more compatible to deal with sum of n^n so that we get a nice closed form?

[Sum of 1.5-powers of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393811/sum-of-1-5-powers-of-natural-numbers)

**Here is an example but using sum of $n^{1.5}$** but how about approximating a closed form for sum of $n^n?$

If there is a nice closed form (a short one), it would be **awesome**.

Comment: Wouldn't that require solving $\int_0^n x^x \, dx$?  As far as I know that integral can only be expressed [in terms of another series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx), which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  You can expand the x^x using taylor series and integrate maybe 3 first terms individually. That's what i did because first 3 terms should have good accuracy already. A

Comment: Would something like $$
n^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{ne}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)
$$ be sufficient?

Comment: @Michael Seifert Hi professor, if there is a closed form for this and yet accurate, that would be so awesome

Comment: @Gary The values are close but can that accuracy be increased further? Any links i can refer to?

Comment: I don't see how the sort of Taylor series approach you're describing would work.  If you're expressing$$x^x = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(x \ln x)^m}{m!}$$and truncating the series at the $M$th term for some fixed $M$, then the remainder term will be of the order $(x \ln x)^M/M!$.  If you then integrate this from 0 to $n$, the integral of this remainder term will get larger as $n$ increases, and your approximation would lose accuracy.

Comment: @Michael Seifert Hi sir, my mistake sorry :)

Comment: The first three terms are not accurate, no. Consider $e^x.$ The first three terms are not a good representation og $e^x$ for $x$ large.

Comment: How about $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^k }  \sim n^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{en}} + \left( {\frac{1}{{2e}} + \frac{1}{{e^2 }}} \right)\frac{1}{{n^2 }} + \left( {\frac{7}{{24e}} + \frac{2}{{e^2 }} + \frac{1}{{e^3 }}} \right)\frac{1}{{n^3 }} +  \cdots } \right)?
$$

Comment: @Gary Wow, that s so accurate! May i know what concept is this and how you derived this?

Comment: Starting from the "end" of the series, $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^k }  = n^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}\left( {\frac{{n - 1}}{n}} \right)^{n - 1}  + \frac{1}{{n^2 }}\left( {\frac{{n - 2}}{n}} \right)^{n - 2}  + \frac{1}{{n^3 }}\left( {\frac{{n - 3}}{n}} \right)^{n - 3}  +  \cdots } \right).
$$ I put $n=1/x$ in the expression inside the parentheses and expanded about $x=0$ using computer algebra system. Then I replaced $x$ by $1/n$. With careful analysis of remainders, this could be made rigorous.

Comment: It may be shown that the coefficient of $\frac{1}{n^m}$ in my expansion will be $$
\frac{1}{{m!}}\left[ {\frac{{d^m }}{{dx^m }}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {x^k e^{ - k} \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{m - k} {\frac{{k^{j + 1} }}{{j(j + 1)}}x^j } } \right)} } \right)} \right]_{x = 0} .
$$

Comment: @Gary Thank you so much for your effort!! Appreciate it!! Takes quite a long time for me to understand as I am new to series :)

Comment: @Gary  How do you get the equation after you said ''Starting from the "end" of the series,'' ?

Comment: @Gary Is it by computer ?

Comment: Just note that $$
1^1  + 2^2  +  \cdots  + (n - 1)^{n - 1}  + n^n  = n^n  + (n - 1)^{n - 1}  +  \cdots \\ = n^n \left( {1 + \frac{{(n - 1)^{n - 1} }}{{n^n }} +  \cdots } \right) = n^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}\left( {\frac{{n - 1}}{n}} \right)^n  +  \cdots } \right).
$$