# Closed form of sum of n^n series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

[image: Series]

Hi readers, may i know how this formula is derived? I thought of using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula which is Euler-Maclaurian to find the formula but its not.

Comment: As far as I know there is no nice closed form for the given sum.

Comment: Hi @Peter do you know how to derive the above expression?

Comment: Isn't deriving the summation just grouping terms with the same exponent?

Comment: Hi @Smriti Sivakumar  If you know the answer, you can post it below so that it benefits all readers.

Comment: You can also write it on a piece of paper and upload it

Comment: $n^n$ has been "factored out" of every summand. The expression in the parantheses can be seen to be smaller than $1+1/n+1/n^2+1/n^3+...$ hence for large $n$, we get a good approximation by truncating at the $1/n^2$-term. Of course the absolute error is large since we multiply with $n^n$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This could have been discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186301/what-is-an-approximate-closed-form-for-sum-of-nn-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I think the summation was derived:$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^k= 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3+....+n^n$$
$$=n^n\left(1+ \frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}+\frac{(n-2)^{n-2}}{n^n}+\frac{(n-3)^{n-3}}{n^n}+...+\frac{1^{1}}{n^n}\right)$$
$$=n^n\left(1+ \frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}\cdot n}+\frac{(n-2)^{n-2}}{n^{n-2}\cdot n^2}+\frac{(n-3)^{n-3}}{n^{n-3}\cdot n^3}+...+\frac{1^{1}}{n^1\cdot n^{n-1}}\right)$$
$$=n^n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}+\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^{n-2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^{n-3}+...+\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Smriti, LOL, i thought this is a closed form but its just simplifying it.

Comment: @MaximusSu haha exactly, i was confused about the question here, hence the "I think"

Comment: so far there is no nice closed form for this right? There is a nice closed form of n^1.5 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393811/sum-of-1-5-powers-of-natural-numbers

Comment: @MaximusSu to my knowledge, no.

Comment: But, its not accurate for n^n, because the number of terms required to cancel the error in Euler-Maclaurian series is just too many.

Comment: @MaximusSu I discussed how to derive the asymptotics here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186301/what-is-an-approximate-closed-form-for-sum-of-nn-series Why did you open a new question?