# How to find the summation of the above series upto $n$ terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I don't know how to find the summation of the above series upto $n$ terms? I know how to find the summation of the series's like $1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+n^2$, $1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots n^3$? The formula of the summation of the 1st series upto $n$ terms is $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ and the formula for the summation of the second series upto $n$ terms is $\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$. But I don't know how to find the summation of the series $1+2^2+3^3+\ldots n^n$? Please help me out.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001923

Comment: ...in other words, as OEIS does not have a closed form, it is highly unlikely that a closed form of this sum is known.

Comment: about summing the reciprocals  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form of sum of n^n series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186651/closed-form-of-sum-of-nn-series)